# Weird behaviour with RenderAction

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, renderaction

On a View I am calling Render action with from within a loop, the action will create an array of objects and return to a PartialView with a Grid to display the results.

View:

```
foreach (var item in Model)
<%Html.RenderAction("GridData", "Customer", new {passidx = (new Random().Next(50))});%>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult GridData(int passidx)
    {
        List<Customer> cList = new List<Customer>{new Customer() { name = "c" + (1 + passidx).ToString(), address = "a" + (1 + passidx).ToString() },
                                                  new Customer() { name = "c" + (2 + passidx).ToString(), address = "a" + (2 + passidx).ToString() }};

        return View(cList);
    }
```

Roughly 2 out of every 3 times I refresh the page the values for each element in the grids are the same even though I am passing a random number to each Action which is appended to the displayed text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of calling `new Random()` in `foreach`, declare one instance before `foreach`. you are getting duplicate because it is using same seed.

See this [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-not-working-the-way-i-had-planned-c/768001#768001).

**Example:**

```
Random random = new Random();
foreach (var item in Model)
<%Html.RenderAction("GridData", "Customer", new {passidx = (random.Next(50))});%>
```

Comment: It's noting to do with Random, if I change it to declare an Int and and increment it in the loop then pass this int exactly the same behaviour occurs

Comment: Further more if I put a break point in the controller the value is always the same even though debugging the view shows different values being passed. It's almost like the values are cached somewhere

Comment: @user621477 I have tried on my system (see example), and it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's the scope of the variable that's causing the problem. If I declare Random or int or whatever inside the loop it doesn't work, moving it outside does.